# Java: initialize data structure once and reuse across JVM(with high latency and no remote calls)

Tags: java, shared-memory

I have a use case where I have to run a java application multiple times.
Performance bottleneck for the application is it's initialization time.
At initialization, application loads 10 million records from disk into memory data structure
and then application does around 100 million lookups in the in-memory data structure.

What I want to do is to avoid loading the records from disk again and again.
And my application to use shared memory for the data structure lookup.
I don't want to use remote method calls/web service call since that would be too costly
for the lookup part.

Also, I don't have the option to use threads.

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't have the option to use threads"?

Comment: How about starting your application once and keeping it running, and then monitoring a file or socket to trigger the start of the calculations?  Though if the input doesn't change would the result of your calculations not just stay the same?

Answer (score 1):

I would build the data structure in memory mapped files. These can be shared between processes and runs of the same process.  Using them is not trivial however as you have to determine how you will structure the data at the byte level. i.e. you can't use Java objects. (On the plus stide this means almost no GC overhead)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should make this application into a server and the command you run should get required data via request-response mechanism.

Another option can be to create a snapshot of the required data which can be very quickly loaded everytime you run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Though I've never used it but looks like [Class Data Sharing](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.user.aix64.60%2Fuser%2Fshc_overview.html) might help you.